# 200 amp feeder wire size?

Tags: electrical

i've got 120' of 350/350/4/4 AL wire from transformer to a  400 amp service entrance meter/panel (Siemens [MM0404L1400RLM](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008KMFNG6)). From there, the 200 amp feeder breaker is going to feed via 2 1/2" conduit to the future house.

That run is 235' to a temporary power panel to be used during construction ( Siemens [PW0816B1200TC](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005GLDQVI)).

Is 4/0,4/0,2/0,#4 good? Or am I not allowed to down-size the neutral?

Comment: What will the major electrical loads be?

Comment: I think the OP is asking about a new service to a 2nd home with a 200 amp panel. With an 83% derate since it is a service for the hots 300 and the Voltage drop will be 2.81%.  the neutral can be derated 70% or 250Kim with a voltage drop of 2.81% I think the original OP calculations did not consider the distance.

Comment: And he should not derate for distance if his actual expected loads do not warrant a derate.  However regardless,  the wire must meet the code minimum for the breaker

Comment: What's the HVAC load in the house, what does it have for hot water/dryer/range (electric or gas), and how many square feet is it?

Answer (score 0):

Your 350/350/4/4 AL for the 400A entrance cable from the meter seems undersized.  even using the residential NEC 310.15 83% of 400 for 332A would require 500KCMIl for the hots and 300 KCMIL for the neutral using the 70% rule at 90C (if your utility allows that).
Unless I missed your point and you are protecting this line with a 200A breaker from the 400Amp panel to feed the future house. (and then, your wire seems perfect!)

Comment: If it was underground SECs or the mast wires, yes, this'd be undersized...the 120' could be underground or overhead though.